# how to change response in xml or json using Yii2 micro

Tags: yii2

Here is my controller

```
class PostController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'micro\models\Post';

    public function behaviors() {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        unset($behaviors['rateLimiter']);
        return $behaviors;
    }

}
```

it will generate API for CRUD,but it is respond in **XML** format.

here is solution for single controller

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ]
    ];
    unset($behaviors['rateLimiter']);
    return $behaviors;
}
```

but I want response in **JSON** format **globally**

Answer (score 0):

#### You can configure the response format globally on the configuration file.

On the `/config/config.php` file `components` section, configure the `response` to return `json`.

```php
'response' => [
    'format' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    'formatters' => [
        Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
            'class' => '\yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
            'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG,
            'encodeOptions' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
        ]
    ]
],
```

There is more information on the [Yii2 documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-response-formatting#controlling-json-output).

Comment: This is working for Advance and basic framwork but, In case of Micro setup, It does`t work.|My controller extends form 'yii\rest\ActiveController'